# Multiple tableviews scrollToTop issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `scrollView` with two embedded `tableView`s. Each of these are placed such that they are shown when I scroll to left and right respectively. Also I have two buttons like tabs, to switch to the respective `tableView`s.

I want the the `tableview`s to `scrollToTop` on tapping the status bar. I referred this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7165943/2954866) and tried the following solution:

On clicking **Button A** or when scrolled to **tableViewA**:

```
tableViewA.scrollsToTop = YES;
tableViewB.scrollsToTop = NO;
scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
```

Implemented similarly for **tableViewB** too.

`scrollToTop` works fine. The issue is that, sometimes, when I `scrollToTop` from **tableviewA**, **tableViewB** comes up, and vice versa.

Please provide your valuable suggestions or a solution to this problem. Thanks!